# Custom font in Android like in iOS

Tags: android, fonts, webview

I am writing an iOS based on a WebView. In iOS you can load custom font and set them in the app plist. In this way you can load them just by referencing the font name. I was wondering if there is something similar to Android that would let me reuse some of the web code used in the ios app and avoid to differentiate the font loading in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/
and http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/?